# Mongo FindByIdsAndName

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I have a schema in mongo like this :

```
_id,
name
```

I want to perform query where I will pass a list of ids and a name to get all the documents whose id matches with the one in input list and name starts with the one in input.

For eg the collection looks like this :

```
_id : 1,
name : stackOverFlow
```

```
_id:2,
name: stacks
```

```
_id:3,
name:queue
```

Now I will pass a list [1,2,3] and a name : "stack".

Expected output :

```
_id:1,
name: stackoverflow
```

```
_id:2,
name:stacks
```

I couldn't find any query which solves this use-case. How can this be done via query using springboot?

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.find({_id:{$in:[idsOfArray]},name:{$regex:/^stack/i})
```